# How to convert time to seconds

Tags: libreoffice-calc, time

I have csv file with cells that have values like 0:20.555 and 12:05.001. The format is mm:ss.sss where mm is minutes,ss.sss is seconds with thousandths of seconds. It is a duration, not time of day. A stop watch reading.

How to convert it to seconds? So 0:20.555 is just 20.555 and 12:05.001 is 725.001?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a new column.
Format it as a numerical type of general.

Assuming the time is in column c1,  enter the following formula in the new cell.

```
=c1 * 24 * 3600
```

Save as csv and it deletes the formulas and places the values in instead.

This has to be times only, not datetimes.

Comment: I'll accept your answer. I had actually tried it already but it didn't work. I am using ,comma as separator instead of .dot. But my times in the csv were in 0:20.000 format instead of 0:20,000. Thanks again.

Comment: in the example i quickly wrote i used a millisecond value. worked fine.

Comment: it worked for you because you probably have setup . as the separator for the numbers in calc as people do in US for example. Some countries use "," instead or ".". So you'd write 50.0 but I'd write 50,0. And 50.0 gives me error, just like 50,0 would probably give you an error.

Comment: you said you were storing these in csv files, how are you using a comma to seperate time components ?   here use this, thats a nonstandard format and a bad one for time storage. https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/sbasic/shared/replace.html

Comment: what you'll have to do is replace the comma with a . and then convert the type back somehow.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator

Comment: oh. you're not using us format. well. i hate to say this i still think you should convert :p call me biased lol